('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
I'm using apache-airflow in windows , while im trying to connect to mssql through odbc im getting this error below:

('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not
found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I have downloaded this https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.9.1/docker-compose.yaml
and directly compose it in vs code....
but while im connecting through normal python code im getting successfull connection
Please, help me to solve this issue. Do i have to makes any changes to my yaml file?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 + setup ODBC connection.

i have done odbc setup and make a successful connection through normal python script , but in apache airflo i is not working

I would imagine the driver per the link is not part of the docker image you have.. No idea how the ODBC connection is made via Docker though. Is your baseline OS a Windows setup?

yes , let me tell you the set up , i have downloaded the docker-compose.yaml file , and then directly compose up(in windows with the help of docker) , then i have downloaded odbc driver 18 for mmsql , thorugh this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 site and then make a test connection in odbc data source administrator

If you were using Windows normally without Docker there would be the extra step at the OS level too. ie. Running the ODBC wizard to create the connection. I have no idea how that occurs with Docker images. I'd be inclined to reach out to the likes of someone like NigelPoulton who's written books on Docker for advice. He's on LinkedIn. https://www.linkedin.com/in/nigelpoulton/
